# How can I use Akka Actors in a Java application?

Tags: java, actor, noclassdeffounderror, akka

I would like to use [Akka actors](http://doc.akka.io/untyped-actors-java) in Java.

I downloaded the `akka-1.0.zip` and added `akka-actor-1.0.jar` to my "Build Path" in Eclipse.

Then I wrote this Actor class:

```
package com.example;

import akka.actor.UntypedActor;

public class MyActor extends UntypedActor {

    public void onReceive(Object message) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (message instanceof String) {
            System.out.println("Received: " + message);
        } else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown message: " + message);
    }
}
```

But I get errors in Eclipse:

```
The type scala.Option cannot be resolved.
The type scala.Some cannot be resolved.
The type scala.PartialFunction cannot be resolved.
The type scala.ScalaObject cannot be resoled.
```

Do I need to add any more files to my "Build Path" or what am I doing wrong? I don't find the documentation beeing that helpful.

**Update:** I added `scala-library.jar` to my Build Path and the above erros disappeared. But I get an error when I compile and run the application:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/lag/configgy/ConfigMap
    at akka.actor.Actors.actorOf(Actors.java:70)
    at com.example.ActorTest.main(ActorTest.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.lag.configgy.ConfigMap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

Here is the main class where I use my actor:

```
package com.example;

import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.Actors;

public class ActorTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ActorRef myActor = Actors.actorOf(MyActor.class);
        myActor.start();
        System.out.println("My Actor started");
    }

}
```

Comment: akka-actor-1.0.jar requires a couple of dependencies, and you can see them here: https://github.com/jboner/akka/blob/v1.0/project/build/AkkaProject.scala#L322     HOWEVER, in akka master, we have now managed to remove _all_ dependencies (except scala-library.jar) for akka-actor.jar

Comment: @Viktor: Thanks, now with `akka-actor-1.1-M1.jar` I only needed to add the `scala-library.jar` (8MB). However, now I tested `akka-typed-actor-1.1-M1.jar` and getting a similar problem: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/aspectwerkz/joinpoint/CodeRtti` What libraries do I have to add now?

Comment: Or it doesn't work that well again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829909/how-can-i-use-a-typedactor-in-a-java-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `akka-1.0.zip` file there is `scala-library.jar`. Try adding it to the build path.

Also, there is a `lib_managed` directory inside the zip, which contains further library files. Possibly aslo some of them will be needed.

To avoid this kind of situations you should try maven. There is a Akka repository: http://scalablesolutions.se/akka/repository/se/scalablesolutions/akka/

Comment: Thanks, I added the `scala-library.jar` to my Build Path, but I still have some error in my application. See my update.

Comment: There is a `configgy-2.0.2-nologgy.jar` in the dir I mentioned.

Comment: Ether you add all jars in this dir to your build path or start using maven which resolves all dependencies automatically.

Comment: So Akka require Maven unless I add **54 jar files** with a size of more than **10MB** including webservers like Jetty. This makes me stay away from Akka. Thanks anyway.

Comment: No Akka does not require maven. Maven is a build tool, very helpful for large teams, because (amongst other things) it resolves dependencies automatically so people do not have to add jars to build path by hand. Akka is a large toolset, so it depends on a lot of libraries. Now, `akka-actors` probably just uses a subset of jars in lib dir, but you won't know until you go through the try-error process you experienced. Normally software projects list their dependencies, but I could not find such list just for `akka-actors`. Anyhow, do try maven. I'm sure you'll find it helpful. I know I do.

Comment: @Jonas - Jesper has posted a link in his answer, that points to an example Maven project for Akka. You should be up and running with Maven in no time. Just copy the pom.xml and remove dependencies from it that you do not directly need. You only need to list dependencies that you code directly needs - indirect dependencies (like you experienced) will be handled automatically.

Comment: Hello, the link to the maven repo seems to be inactive currently.

Comment: Akka is now in central repo: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22akka%22

Answer (score 2):

You can find a complete, working example [here](https://github.com/alexaverbuch/akka_chat_java); it's a Maven project, so it will get the dependencies for you automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I see this problem using Akka in a Java project in Eclipse with the Scala IDE installed. The problem goes away when using an Eclipse instance without the Scala IDE installed. Eclipse is perhaps confused by two Scala libraries around?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Akka actors but it seems you need some scala support (libs on the build path) as well.