# How can I use a TypedActor in a Java application?

Tags: java, actor, akka, typedactor

I try to implement a `TypedActor` in Java following the examples on [Typed Actors (Java)](http://doc.akka.io/typed-actors-java). But I'm struggling. I have added `akka-actor-1.1-M1.jar`, `akka-typed-actor-1.1-M1.jar`, `scala-library.jar` but it wasn't enough. I got errors in Eclipse so I also added `aspectwerkz-2.0.jar` and `aspectwerkz-core-2.0.jar` to my Build Path.

I try to use a TypedActor with custom constructor.

But now I get an error at compilation:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.proxy.Proxy.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Object;ZZ)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at akka.actor.TypedActor$.newInstance(TypedActor.scala:596)
    at akka.actor.TypedActor$.newInstance(TypedActor.scala:634)
    at akka.actor.TypedActor.newInstance(TypedActor.scala)
    at com.example.actor.ActorTest.main(ActorTest.java:12)
```

Here is my code for the `BaseActor`:

```
import akka.actor.TypedActor;

public class BaseActor extends TypedActor implements BaseService {

    private String str;
    private int num;

    public BaseActor(String str, int num) {
    this.str = str;
    this.num = num;
        System.out.println("booted");
    }

    public void testData(String str, int num) {
        System.out.println(this.str + " " + this.num);
        System.out.println(str + " " + num);
    }
}
```

My `interface` for the service:

```
public interface BaseService {

    public void testData(String str, int num);
}
```

And a test class:

```
import akka.actor.TypedActor;
import akka.actor.TypedActorFactory;

public class ActorTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BaseService service = TypedActor.newInstance(BaseService.class,
                                                     new TypedActorFactory() {
            public TypedActor create() {
                return new BaseActor("someString", 12);
            }
        });

        service.testData("Hello", 6);
    }

}
```

In the example they write:

```
Service service = TypedActor.newInstance(classOf[Service], 
                                         new TypedActorFactory() {
  public TypedActor create() {
    return new ServiceWithConstructorArgsImpl("someString", 500L));
});
```

But I don't think that `classOf[Service]` is Java, it's looks more like Scala.

How can I implement an `TypedActor` with a custom constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct, as far as I can see.
To instantiate a TypedActor in Java with a non default constructor, you should use:

```
BaseService service = TypedActor.newInstance(BaseService.class,
                                                     new TypedActorFactory() {
            public TypedActor create() {
                return new BaseActor("someString", 12);
            }
        });
```

Indeed, the official doc contains a typo.

Can you try to use aspectwerkz-2.2.3? I have tried your code and it does work for me. The only difference is the version of aspectwerkz I'm using.

Also, please note that these are the dependencies for akka-typed-actor 1.1-M1:

```
<dependency org="org.codehaus.aspectwerkz" name="aspectwerkz" rev="2.2.3" force="true" conf="compile->compile(*),master(*);runtime->runtime(*)"/>
<dependency org="aopalliance" name="aopalliance" rev="1.0" force="true" conf="compile->compile(*),master(*);runtime->runtime(*)"/>
<dependency org="org.guiceyfruit" name="guice-all" rev="2.0" force="true" conf="compile->compile(*),master(*);runtime->runtime(*)"/>
<dependency org="se.scalablesolutions.akka" name="akka-stm" rev="1.1-M1" force="true" conf="compile->compile(*),master(*);runtime->runtime(*)"/>
<dependency org="org.scala-lang" name="scala-library" rev="2.9.0.RC1" force="true" conf="compile->compile(*),master(*);runtime->runtime(*)"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. I can only find AspectWerkz 2.0 on the latest realeses: http://aspectwerkz.codehaus.org/releases.html Where can I find the 2.2.3? I have tried to add the other dependencies now, but it didn't help.

Comment: Cool, I think that the aspektwerkz version that comes with Akka is a "customized" version of the original library (Jonas Boner, founder of akka was also the founder of aspektwerkz). That is why is not available on the aspektwerkz web site.