# Why return type of AKKA actor postStop not void?

Tags: java, akka

In overriding the postStop method I got this very strange:
[error message from illelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4y1C.png)

the class is very simple:

```
public class TempClass extends AbstractActor {
      @Override
      public void postStop(){}
}
```

the [api](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/index.html?akka/actor/package-summary.html&_ga=2.160853880.456463205.1511289640-876455994.1506327289) indicates the return type is void, do I miss something in my code?

Comment: Yes postStop has void return type, your signature is right, I think there is something else that you were miss in your code. Please check your code properly.

Answer (score 1):

Answer my own question:
The problem is the scala-library.jar is not added [scala-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245449/how-can-i-use-akka-actors-in-a-java-application)

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix the scala and java API or you will be in for a lot of headaches. Look at the imports and so on. Also make sure you are up to date with the version of Akka.